# Hatcher's fundamental group of circle explanation

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, covering-spaces

I am quite confused of the wording on Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) (p29-30) proof particularly this part:

---

[image]

What does he mean by "*A unique lift $\tilde{F}: I \times \{ 0 \} \rightarrow \tilde{X}$ is obtained by an application of (a)*"?

---

My understanding is $F: I \times \{0 \} \rightarrow X$ is a path, and by requiring $\tilde{F}(0 \times 0) = \tilde{x_0}$, where $\tilde{x_0} \in p^{-1}[F( 0 \times 0)]$ ($p$ is covering map), we obtain a unique path $\tilde{F}:I \times \{0\} \rightarrow \tilde{X}$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.